# Ideal in $k[x,y]$ generated by two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose $k$ is a finite field of order $q$.
Let $f = \prod_{1 \leq i \leq s} (x + b_i y)$
and let  $g = \prod_{1 \leq i \leq t} (x + c_i y)$,
where $b_i, c_j 
\in k.$ I am interested in finding out
what is the ideal generated by $f$ and $g$ when
they don't have a common factor.
Thanks!

Comment: @user121097 Thanks! sorry I just realized I made a small mistake! I fixed the error.

Comment: Did you tried some particular cases? What about $(X^2-Y^2, X+2Y)$? This looks like $(X^2,Y^2,XY,X+2Y)$. All I can say for all cases is that some powers of $X$ and $Y$ belong to your ideal, so its radical is always $(X,Y)$.

Comment: I haven't tried particular cases yet, but I will. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies. I actually haven't quite looked at a particular case yet... In stead so far what I got was that this ideal $I = (f,g)$ will contain any form in $k[x,y]$ of degree $N$ as long as $N \geq s+t-1$. At the moment I was thinking about maybe do something with this...